# Print out the elements in a string

Tags: python

I have values that look like this

```
 <type 'str'> 
['zeven', 'nul', 'zeven', 'een', 'pieter', 'marie']
```

What I would like to do now is to loop over all the elements. However if I do like this:

```
x = ['zeven', 'nul', 'zeven', 'een', 'pieter', 'marie']

for word in x:
 print(x)
```

I get:

```
 [
 '
 z
 e
```

Any thoughts how I can just get the values (like zeven, nul... etc...)

Comment: `for word in ast.literal_eval(x)`...

Comment: Looks like for some reason you have a repr of a list of strings. You could `ast.literal_eval` it but honestly this looks like something  that needs to be fixed upstream.

Comment: That output isn't what I get when I run your code. Are you 100% sure that's exactly the code you're running? If you're thinking "I said I'm doing _like_ this, not _exactly_ this", please share a [mcve] that exactly shows what you're doing.

Comment: @Kevin OP forgot quotation marks around his list. edit: forgot in the sense that he actually has a string that he loops over.

Comment: Even if he did `x = "['zeven'...`, he still wouldn't get the output he described.

Comment: @Kevin oh, I see. Then I suppose the `print(x)` is a typo.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there, you should not print x but you should print word for each word in the list.

```
x = ['zeven', 'nul', 'zeven', 'een', 'pieter', 'marie']

for word in x:
    print(word)
```

this will give you the following output:

```
zeven
nul
zeven
een
pieter
marie
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have something like this:

```
x = "['zeven', 'nul', 'zeven', 'een', 'pieter', 'marie']"
```

So you will need to use `eval()`:

```
for word in eval(x):
    print word
```

Comment: I don't think this is good advice because OP's problem is probably better fixed by not having this string at all.

Comment: I'm not sure he might get that string/list from elsewhere so I just used it as a decoration.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` is better. Prevents malicious users from breaking your system by putting in strings like `"__import__('os').system('delete_hard_drive.exe')"`.

Comment: Yeah I'm waiting for OP to update the question such that it makes sense.

Comment: I'm sure this is not production code....